# Over Lapping mysql data output on PDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am trying to get single mysql field(quantity) record output (4 times per page) in various position on a page using php and fpdf class. I can get the output on pdf but all the record for that field are overlapping each other. can anyone please help me to find out where I am wrong on my code....

```html
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
 
 mysql_select_db("Product"); 
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product_Type where id='$id'"); 
   
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  
  $Quantity = $row["Quantity"];
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);   
  $pdf->SetXY(15,60);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 50, $row['Quantity']);
  $pdf->SetXY(100,60);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 50, $row['Quantity']);
  $pdf->SetXY(15,110);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 50, $row['Quantity']);
  $pdf->SetXY(100,110);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 50, $row['Quantity']);
  $pdf->SetXY(15,160);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 50, $row['Quantity']);
  
  
   }
```

[image]
thanks in advance for your kind support!

Comment: You're using the same cells/position in every loop and I don't see you changing the page at all. Change one of these things at least!

Comment: i dont have any idea how to change the cell position. can you advice it little bit more

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation. http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setxy.htm

Comment: do you want to print in 4 corner per page?

Comment: I want to print based on my query position